# PHP session dropped when filename is stripped

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, ini

This is a quick question, that has been bugging me for quite some time!

I have a page`www.example.com/dir/index.php` which sets a `$_SESSION` variable. I access this variable again on `www.example.com/dir/dir2/dostuff.php` and this works fine!

However, if I set the session through `www.example.com/dir/` it isn't set in `www.example.com/dir/dir2/dostuff.php`.

I have rewritten the .htaccess with

```
RewriteRule ^.*\/dir\/$ /dir/index.php [NC]
```

and set my php.ini in index.php using:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

However without results.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Update:**

In a nutshell index.php simply runs:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$_SESSION['param'] = "val";
```

The dostuff.php runs:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
echo $_SESSION['param'];
```

Comment: Explain how you set your session?

Comment: Does `index.php` contain a `session_start()`? If it's redirecting to there first, it may not be keeping the session alive. Make sure you're calling it on every page.

Comment: Yes every page has session_start()..

Comment: have you tried `session_set_cookie_params` instead?

Comment: Okay, one solution is to define a folder to save the sessions in with `session_save_path('sessions');` and locate that folder with it's relative path `session_save_path('../sessions');` but there must be an easier solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

From [`session_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> **session_start()** creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

You should call `session_start()` unconditionally, when you want to access `_SESSION` variables.